# Laravel return home with locale parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I am setting my routes with a locale paremeter that gets 'pt' or 'en' and sets the locale as that paremeter, when I log in I can't get it to pass with that parameter.

Example :

```
Route::get('{locale}/register', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('auth.register', ['locale' => $locale]);
})->name('register_lang')->middleware('guest');
```

Home route :

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Home Controller :

```
public function index($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('home', ['locale' => $locale]);
}
```

The home is set in RouteServiceProvider, I would like it to pass it with the locale parameter, how would I do it?

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

Comment: Add `App::getLocale().'/home'` as HOME route.

Comment: In The RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: Yes. Try with this. hope it will work

Comment: public const HOME = App::getLocale().'/home'; I get Expression is not allowed as class constant value

Comment: RouteServiceProvider : https://pastebin.com/eHXuFhj1

Comment: Added in anwser. You have to ovverride `redirectTo()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `LoginController` you can override method instead of modifying in service provider.

```
  protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        return redirect()->to(app()->getLocale()."/home");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `redirectTo()` method in LoginController. This will override the constant `HOME`

```php
public function redirectTo() : string
{
    return App::getLocale().'/home';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Made an hidden input with the locale value in the login view and accessed it through the request.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    App::setLocale($request->locale);
    return redirect(route('home', ['locale' => $request->locale]));
}
```